# FAT32 - Unallocated space within partition

Tags: fat32

I have an SD card with 3 partitions: FAT32, EXT4 and swap. I shrank and moved them recently, but due to a bug in GParted (segfault while resizing FAT32) it is left like this:

**Size**: 5.87 GiB

**Used**: 623 MiB

**Unused**: 4.37 GiB

**Unallocated**: 915 MiB

GParted suggests me to repair the partition with Partition -> Check, but there's that bug. Any other tools which can do the same thing - expand fat32 size to the same as in the partition table? I tried `dosfsck/fsck.vfat` and MS `chkdsk`, none of them helped.

Comment: FWIW, using flash memory for swap space may reduce its lifespan. OTOH, if you have enough RAM, swap will rarely be used. It's nice to have some swap space, just in case you _do_ need it, but it's much better to use a partition or file on a real disk, if possible.  Also, it _may_ impact the proper operation of an SD card if you [reformat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Risks_of_reformatting) it. But if you _do_ reformat it's a good idea to mount the partition with the `noatime` option, to avoid writes to the card on every access.

Comment: It's for Android booted from SD on a phone, I know it doesn't need swap, but well, I can always add some to be mounted manually on boot for kernel and /bin executables.

Comment: Ok. Android probably uses noatime by default. And hopefully it won't thrash your swap partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fatresize](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fatresize). Be sure to tell it the right partition size, beware of rounding and of different units (SI vs 1024-based). Run `grep sdb1 /proc/partitions` to get the size of the partition in units of 1024 bytes, and run `fatresize -s NNNki /dev/sdb1` (change `sdb1` to the actual name of the partition of course).

Comment: This didn't work. I tried entering larger numbers to fatresize, but nothing changed.
_fatresize -i /dev/sdc1_ says:
Size: 5347737600
Min size: 655062016
Max size: 7969177600 even after _sudo fatresize -s 6159360ki /dev/sdc1_

Comment: Ok, it worked, but I had to use a card reader (somehow the phone was preventing fatresize to work). Thanks ;)